# How to regulate rounds in a simple game?

Tags: python, list

The board game requires 20 rounds. The board itself is ciruclar, meaning after slot 10 the player returns to slot 1. I definded the amount of rounds but still in my code the amount of rounds is rather random. I do not understand what is wrong with my code?

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
@dataclass
class Player:    
    firstname: str    
    lastname: str   
    coins: int    
    slot: int
    def full_info(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.firstname} {self.lastname} {self.coins} {self.slot}"
    @classmethod
    def from_user_input(cls) -> 'Player':        
        return cls(
            firstname=input("Please enter your first name:"),            
            lastname=input("Please enter your second name: "),            
            coins=200,            
            slot= 0)
minplayer, maxplayer, n = 2, 5, -1
while not(minplayer <= n <= maxplayer):  
    n = int(input(f" Choose a number of players between {minplayer} and {maxplayer}: "))    
playersingame = []   #storing it in the list
for i in range(n):   
    playersingame.append(Player.from_user_input())
print([player.full_info() for player in playersingame])
# The board
board = [[ ] for i in range(10)]
for player in playersingame:    
    board[ player.slot ].append(player)
print(board)
import random    
for player in playersingame:    
    input(f"{player.firstname} {player.lastname}, please press enter to roll your die...")    
    die = random.randint(1,6)    
    print(f"You take {die} step{'s'* (die>1)} forward")    
    board[player.slot].remove(player)    
    player.slot += die    
    board[player.slot].append(player)
print(board)

def shift(seq, n=0):
    a = n % len(seq)
    return seq[-a:] + seq[:-a]
round_counter=1
rounds=30
while (round_counter <= rounds):    
    for player in playersingame:        
        input(f"{player.firstname} {player.lastname}, please press enter to roll your die...")        
        die = random.randint(1,6)        
        print(f"You take {die} step{'s'*(die>1)} forward")        
        board[player.slot].remove(player)        
        player.slot += die
        if board[player.slot] == len(board):
            shift(board)
        board[player.slot-1].append(player)
       
    print(board)
    round_counter = round_counter+1
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
player.slot += die
if board[player.slot] == len(board):
    shift(board)
board[player.slot-1].append(player)
```

try:

```
player.slot = (player.slot + die) % len(board)
board[player.slot].append(player)
```

Your shift function returns a result, but it's never assigned, and it's not clear from the original code how you intend the slots of all the *other* players would get updated.

If there's an (unstated) reason why the board needs to shift beneath the players, notice that a player's slot **could overshoot** the length of the board and you may need to test for `board[player.slot] >= len(board)` instead.
(E.g. when `player.slot` is 8 and `die` is 4, after `player.slot += die` -- `player.slot` is now 12, since the addition is done in one go and never equals `len(board)` )